# Альтернатива этому коду на python

Tags: c#, python, windows, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть такой код на c#:

```
public class ProcessManager
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetKernelObjectSecurity(IntPtr Handle, int securityInformation, [Out] byte[] pSecurityDescriptor,
uint nLength, out uint lpnLengthNeeded);

        public static RawSecurityDescriptor GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(IntPtr processHandle)
        {
            const int DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004;
            byte[] psd = new byte[0];
            uint bufSizeNeeded;
            // Call with 0 size to obtain the actual size needed in bufSizeNeeded
            GetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, psd, 0, out bufSizeNeeded);
            if (bufSizeNeeded < 0 || bufSizeNeeded > short.MaxValue)
                throw new Win32Exception();
            // Allocate the required bytes and obtain the DACL
            if (!GetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            psd = new byte[bufSizeNeeded], bufSizeNeeded, out bufSizeNeeded))
                throw new Win32Exception();
            // Use the RawSecurityDescriptor class from System.Security.AccessControl to parse the bytes:
            return new RawSecurityDescriptor(psd, 0);
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetKernelObjectSecurity(IntPtr Handle, int securityInformation, [In] byte[] pSecurityDescriptor);

        public static void SetProcessSecurityDescriptor(IntPtr processHandle, RawSecurityDescriptor dacl)
        {
            const int DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004;
            byte[] rawsd = new byte[dacl.BinaryLength];
            dacl.GetBinaryForm(rawsd, 0);
            if (!SetKernelObjectSecurity(processHandle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, rawsd))
                throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [Flags]
        public enum ProcessAccessRights
        {
            PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x0080, //  Required to create a process.
            PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002, //  Required to create a thread.
            PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE = 0x0040, // Required to duplicate a handle using DuplicateHandle.
            PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400, //  Required to retrieve certain information about a process, such as its token, exit code, and priority class (see OpenProcessToken, GetExitCodeProcess, GetPriorityClass, and IsProcessInJob).
            PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000, //  Required to retrieve certain information about a process (see QueryFullProcessImageName). A handle that has the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right is automatically granted PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION. Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000:  This access right is not supported.
            PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION = 0x0200, //    Required to set certain information about a process, such as its priority class (see SetPriorityClass).
            PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x0100, //  Required to set memory limits using SetProcessWorkingSetSize.
            PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME = 0x0800, // Required to suspend or resume a process.
            PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x0001, //  Required to terminate a process using TerminateProcess.
            PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008, //   Required to perform an operation on the address space of a process (see VirtualProtectEx and WriteProcessMemory).
            PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010, //    Required to read memory in a process using ReadProcessMemory.
            PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020, //   Required to write to memory in a process using WriteProcessMemory.
            DELETE = 0x00010000, // Required to delete the object.
            READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000, //   Required to read information in the security descriptor for the object, not including the information in the SACL. To read or write the SACL, you must request the ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY access right. For more information, see SACL Access Right.
            SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000, //    The right to use the object for synchronization. This enables a thread to wait until the object is in the signaled state.
            WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000, //  Required to modify the DACL in the security descriptor for the object.
            WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000, //    Required to change the owner in the security descriptor for the object.
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000f0000,
            PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFF),//    All possible access rights for a process object.
        }
        public void block()
        {
            // Get the current process handle
            IntPtr hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
            // Read the DACL
            var dacl = GetProcessSecurityDescriptor(hProcess);
            // Insert the new ACE
            dacl.DiscretionaryAcl.InsertAce(
            0,
            new CommonAce(
            AceFlags.None,
            AceQualifier.AccessDenied,
            (int)ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
            false,
            null)
            );
            // Save the DACL
            SetProcessSecurityDescriptor(hProcess, dacl);
        }
    }
```

Он делает так, что при нажатии в диспетчере задач, в windows, писалось: "Не удалось завершить процесс"
 [image: Картинка]

Есть ли альтернатива этому коду на python?

Comment: Есть ли альтернатива этому коду на python? Очень вероятно что есть.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону ```ctypes``` (```windll``` и т.д.)